# Multiple callbacks in express

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I have 2 schemas : Blogdemo and Review. Both  in the same file : landing.ejs
I want both the content of both the schemas to appear on the landing page.

Code :

```
   app.get('/', function (req, res,next) {
      Blogdemo.find({}).sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(3).exec(function(err,allBlogs) { //finds the latest blog posts (upto 3)
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("landing", {blog : allBlogs , moment : now});
        }
    })
     next();
    }, function (req, res) {
      Review.find({}).sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(3).exec(function(err,allReviews) { //finds the latest reviews (upto 3)
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.render("landing", {review : allReviews, moment : now});
                }   
    })
})
```

I get the error : "review is not defined". If I change the order of the callbacks, I get the error : "blog is not defined". I understand that something is wrong with the callbacks.

I browsed through the express docs and used this :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl)
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
  next()
})
```

This works perfectly.But I'm following the exact pattern and it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MukeshSoni 4.14.0

Comment: try moving next() right after else block in above callback

Comment: @AsifSaeed Didn't work.

Comment: just to give a try move Review.find block next to res.render("landing", {blog : allBlogs , moment : now});

Comment: can you please paste your landing.ejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you are doing one thing wrong: placing `next()` outside the async scope.

Try this:

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        Blogdemo.find({}).sort([
            ['_id', -1]
        ]).limit(3).exec(function(err, allBlogs) { //finds the latest blog posts (upto 3)
            if (err) next(err);
            res.locals.blog = allBlogs;
            res.locals.moment = now;
            next();
        })
    }, function(req, res) {
        Review.find({}).sort([
            ['_id', -1]
        ]).limit(3).exec(function(err, allReviews) { //finds the latest reviews (upto 3)
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.locals.review = allReviews;
            res.render("landing", res.locals); // 2nd argument is optional.
        })
    })
```

Comment: I want a column for blog post, 1 for reviews , something like this :

News : 

[Article 1] ,[Article 2], [Article 3]

Reviews : 

[Review 1],[ Review 2] , [Review 3]

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! So what we're doing is storing variables in res.locals and using from there? Is the next() still necessary?

Comment: Yes it is. I suggest you read express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are doing wrong is `rendering` same page 2 times with `res.render` and passing one of the two variables each time, that's why the other one is coming as undefined.

You should `render` the `landing` page in the last `callback`, and just pass `variables` from first `callback` to second.

To pass variables from one callback to another, you can use `res.locals`.

Also, you should put `next()` inside the callback of `find`. so that it passes the variable to next callback correctly.

Try this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res,next) {
      Blogdemo.find({}).sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(3).exec(function(err,allBlogs) { //finds the latest blog posts (upto 3)
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            next();
        } else {
            //set variable in `res.locals` and pass to next callback
            res.locals.blog = allBlogs;
            next();
        }
    })
}, function (req, res) {
      Review.find({}).sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(3).exec(function(err,allReviews) { //finds the latest reviews (upto 3)
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    allBlogs = res.locals.blog;
                    res.render("landing", {blog : allBlogs ,review : allReviews, moment : now});
                }   
    })
})
```

For more information on res.locals read [Express res.locals documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: In the else in 2nd callback, shouldn't it be : res.locals.review = allReviews; ? And if that's the case, won't allBlogs be defined because of scope issue?

Comment: Hey, I see that you've answered some questions on mongodb. Could you help me this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898336/mongodb-schema-defining