# Mongodb schema defining

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Coding a news/media website, I want a "News" section, "Reviews" section, a
"Trending" section, which combines both the previous sections, just like here:
[image]
I have made one schema for "News", one for "Reviews".How can I make a "Trending" section(as in the image above "Movies" section)?
Code : 
In app.js,

```
 //LANDING PAGE
    app.get('/', function (req, res,next) {
      Blogdemo.find({}).sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(3).exec(function(err,allBlogs) { //finds latest posts for 1st Schema (upto 3)
            if(err) {    
                console.log(err);
                next();
            } else {
                res.locals.blog = allBlogs;
                // res.render("landing", {blog : allBlogs , moment : now});
                next();
            }

        })

}, function (req, res) {
  Review.find({}).sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(3).exec(function(err,allReviews) { //finds latest posts of 2nd Schema
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.locals.review = allReviews;
                    res.render("landing", res.locals);
                }   
    })
})
```

In review.js ,

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//SCHEMA SETUP
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image : String,
    title : String,
    body : String,
    rating : String,
    created : {type : Date, default : Date.now()},
    comments: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment" //name of the model
      }
   ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("review", reviewSchema);
```

The "News" schema is almost the same(no review).
Is my way of defining schema wrong? If not, then how can I build the "Trending" section?

Is there any mongodb method which can find the latest posts from "News" and "Reviews" to build the "Trending" section(just like in 1st picture)?

Comment: have you defined schema for trending section?

Comment: Also, can you show me the schema of review and news, so that i can help you with Trending section.

Comment: I haven't defined a schema for trending section. I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: @RaviShankar If possible, could you give me your email? I don't think we'll get a solution by interacting through comments.

Comment: we can talk on chat.stackoverflow.com too, i had sent you a message too

Comment: Continuation of the [chat discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35529144#35529144). Could you edit your question to add how you insert the "Blog" in your "Trending" base?

Comment: @DrakaSAN That would mean editing the entire question. Is it okay if I send it in yesterday's chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see from your code, your current `News` and `Review` Schema looks fine.

You need to define another `Schema` for `Trending`.

```
var TrendingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    referenceId : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
    postType : String //To store News or Reviews
});
```

While saving new `News` or `Reviews`, insert the `_id` of newly saved document in the `trending` collection.

```
var news = new News();
news.image = newsImage;
...
news.save(function(err,result)
{
    if(!err)
    {
        var trending =  new Trending();
        trending.referenceId = result._id;
        trending.postType = "News";
        treding.save(function(err)
        {
            if(!err)
            {
                //success response
            }
            else
            {
                //error  response
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //send error response
    }
});
```

Similarly while saving Review Post

```
var review = new Review();
review.image = reviewImage;
...
review.save(function(err,result)
{
    if(!err)
    {
        var trending =  new Trending();
        trending.referenceId = result._id;
        trending.postType = "review"
        treding.save(function(err)
        {
            if(!err)
            {
                //success response
            }
            else
            {
                //error  response
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //send error response
    }
});
```

Thus now `Trending` Collection will contain, newly saved `News` or `Review`, in the order they are `created`. Thus you will be able to get new `Review` or `News` Post.

While fetching `Trending`, you can `populate` them using `News` or `Review` `Schema` based on the `postType`.

```
Trendign.find({}).limit(10).exec(function(err,result)
{
    if(!err && result.length!=0)
    {
        var trendingPosts = [];
        result.forEach(function(trending){
            if(trending.postType === "News"){
                trending.populate({path : 'referenceId',model : 'News'},function(err,populatedItem)
                {
                    if(!err)
                    {
                        trendingPosts.push(populatedItem);
                    }
                });
            }
            else if(trending.postType === "Review"){
                trending.populate({path : 'referenceId',model : 'Review'},function(err,populatedItem)
                {
                    if(!err)
                    {
                        trendingPosts.push(populatedItem);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //now send the trendingPost array with latest News and Review Posts
    }
    else
    {
        //send Error response
    }
});
```

Now you can show the latest `News` or `Review` and write the type `postType`.

Hope this is what you want.